# how to create spin buttons in java?

Tags: java

I would like to create ( call) spin buttons (with up/down arrows) in java, any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can learn how to create spin buttons in the Java online documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html

Have a nice day.